# 0 Active Connection on my-new-coin

Tags: client, development, network, altcoin

I have compiled my-newcoin-qt and my-newcoind on different platforms (windows, Linux and Mac), with my coin specification based on litecoin.

When I run my-newcoin-qt at the first time, I get no error but the message:

```
0 Active Connections
```

What should I do as the next step? Should I compile seeder software on VPS server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bought a droplet on DigitalOcean running Ubuntu 12.04. It is only $5/month. I opened the port, compiled my *coind program on it, created my .conf file and ran it. Now my client coin programs connect to it.

Comment: thank you, is that possible to run *coind and software seeder together on one server? (e.g VPS Server)

Comment: unfortunately I am not sure about that. I am still setting my coin nodes up too. I don't see why not, however. You should be able to just run *coind in addition to the seeder software. Also, I am assuming you have seen this: https://github.com/sipa/bitcoin-seeder